# how to extract multiple lines between header and footer in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

if I have a bash variable that contains the following string:

```
my signed 1.5 tag
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1

iQEcBAABAgAGBQJTZbQlAAoJEF0+sviABDDrZbQH/09PfE51KPVPlanr6q1v4/Ut
LQxfojUWiLQdg2ESJItkcuweYg+kc3HCyFejeDIBw9dpXt00rY26p05qrpnG+85b
hM1/PswpPLuBSr+oCIDj5GMC2r2iEKsfv2fJbNW8iWAXVLoWZRF8B0MfqX/YTMbm
ecorc4iXzQu7tupRihslbNkfvfciMnSDeSvzCpWAHl7h8Wj6hhqePmLm9lAYqnKp
8S5B/1SSQuEAjRZgI4IexpZoeKGVDptPHxLLS38fozsyi0QyDyzEgJxcJQVMXxVi
RUysgqjcpT8+iQM1PblGfHR4XAhuOqN5Fx06PSaFZhqvWFezJ28/CLyX5q+oIVk=
=EFTF
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    Change version number
```

in bash, how can extract the base64 signature and store it in a new variable, so that it will contain exactly

```
iQEcBAABAgAGBQJTZbQlAAoJEF0+sviABDDrZbQH/09PfE51KPVPlanr6q1v4/Ut
LQxfojUWiLQdg2ESJItkcuweYg+kc3HCyFejeDIBw9dpXt00rY26p05qrpnG+85b
hM1/PswpPLuBSr+oCIDj5GMC2r2iEKsfv2fJbNW8iWAXVLoWZRF8B0MfqX/YTMbm
ecorc4iXzQu7tupRihslbNkfvfciMnSDeSvzCpWAHl7h8Wj6hhqePmLm9lAYqnKp
8S5B/1SSQuEAjRZgI4IexpZoeKGVDptPHxLLS38fozsyi0QyDyzEgJxcJQVMXxVi
RUysgqjcpT8+iQM1PblGfHR4XAhuOqN5Fx06PSaFZhqvWFezJ28/CLyX5q+oIVk=
=EFTF
```

I tried various combinations of sed or awk but didn't get any working that preserves the line breaks

Comment: suggestion: `I tried various combinations of sed or awk` add some code to the question to avoid downvote/close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using *bash* parameter expansions

```
signature=${string#*$'\n'-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----$'\n'}
signature=${signature#*$'\n\n'}
signature=${signature%%$'\n'-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----*}
```

The first assignment removes the part from the beginning of the string to the line consisting of `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----`. The second one removes the part to the first blank line. The third removes the part from the `-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----` to the end of the string. The remaining string is the base64 signature.

Explanation of parameter expansion forms used in the answer:
`${var#pattern}` is replaced by the content of the variable `var` with the **shortest** matching `pattern` deleted (from the beginning), if the `pattern` matches the **leading** portion of the content of the variable `var`.
`${var%%pattern}` is replaced by the content of the variable `var` with the **longest** matching `pattern` deleted (from the end), if the `pattern` matches the **trailing** portion of the content of the variable `var`.
For detailed information on all forms of *bash* parameter expansion, read the [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: This worked great, thank you! to make the answer perfect, could you explain the different symbols you're using in these calls?

Comment: @matthias_buehlmann An explanation added.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -n '/---/,/---/{/---/n;/^Version/{n;n};p}'`

Between the `---` lines, use `n` to skip the lines that you don't want.  Otherwise `p` to print them.

Could obviously expand the regexes to be a bit more strict.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the empty lines around the signature is always present:

```sh
awk -v RS= 'sub(/\n-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----/, ""){print; exit}'
```

- `-v RS=` paragraph mode, record separator will be two or more consecutive newlines
- `sub(/\n-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----/, "")` if this substitution succeeds

  - `print; exit` print the modified record and quit
  - `\n` is used in the substitution since default ORS is newline

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a bash variable `str` holds the mentioned string, would you please try:

```
pat=$'-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----\n.*\n\n([^-]+)\n-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----'
if [[ $str =~ $pat ]]; then
    signature=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    echo "$signature"
fi
```